# ASP.NET MVC : insert HTML table into database with other form data

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to develop an ASP.NET MVC project for product creation. Currently, I have the following code:

Model:

```
public class ProductModel
{
    public string ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
    public string ProductBrandID { get; set; }
    public string ProductBrandName { get; set; }
    public string ProductCategoryID { get; set; }
    public string ProductCategoryName { get; set; }
    public string Inventory { get; set; }
    public string Photos { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public decimal Discount { get; set; }
    public decimal Tax { get; set; }
    public List<ProductModel> Products { get; set; }
}
```

View

(It has a form that contains some fields about the product and a table for the inventory.)

```
<div class="modal-body" style="padding-left:40px;padding-right:40px">
        <br />
        @using (Html.BeginForm("CreateProduct", "Admin", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <form class="Product">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-7" style="padding-right:20px">

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                                Product Name: <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtNewProductname" name="ProductName">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            Description: <textarea class="form-control" cols="40" rows="2" id="txtNewProductDescription" name="ProductDescription"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                Brand: <select id="selectNewProductBrand" class="form-control" name="ProductBrandID">
                                    <option hidden disabled selected> </option>
                                    @foreach (var item in Model.BrandMenus)
                                    {
                                        <option value="@Html.DisplayFor(module => item.BrandID)">@Html.DisplayFor(module => item.BrandName)</option>
                                    }
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                                Category: <select id="selectNewProductCategory" class="form-control" name="ProductCategoryID">
                                    <option hidden disabled selected> </option>
                                    @foreach (var item in Model.Categories)
                                    {
                                        <option value="@Html.DisplayFor(module => item.CategoryID)">@Html.DisplayFor(module => item.CategoryName)</option>
                                    }
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-sm-4 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                                Price: <input type="text" class="form-control" style="text-align:right;" id="txtNewProductPrice" name="Price">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                Discount: <input type="text" class="form-control" style="text-align:right;" id="txtNewProductDiscount" name="Discount">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                Tax: <input type="text" class="form-control" style="text-align:right;" id="txtNewProductTax" name="Tax">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-sm-5" style="border: thin solid lightgray;border-radius: 15px;padding:20px">
                        Photos:
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    Inventory:<table class="table table-bordered" id="newTableInventory" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th hidden>Inventory ID</th>
                                <th>Variant</th>
                                <th>Stock</th>
                                <th hidden>Location ID</th>
                                <th>Location</th>
                                <th>Remarks</th>
                                <th width="100px">Action</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td hidden>1000001</td>
                                <td>Blue</td>
                                <td>3</td>
                                <td hidden>123</td>
                                <td>Shop</td>
                                <td>Ok</td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#CreateNewVariantModal" class="d-none d-sm-inline-block btn btn-sm btn-primary shadow-sm">
                        <i class="fas fa-plus fa-sm text-white-50"></i> Add Variant
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" id="btnNewProduct" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                </div>

            </form>
        }
</div>
```

**UI**
[image]

**Controller**

```cs
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult CreateProduct(ProductModel objModel)
    {
        ProductModelDal cmProducts = new ProductModelDal();
        try
        {
            int result = cmProducts.CreateProduct(objModel);
            if (result == 1)
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "Product has been added successfully";
                ModelState.Clear();
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "Unsucessfull";
                ModelState.Clear();
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Products");
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
    
public class ProductModelDal
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.CLDBConString);

    public int CreateProduct(ProductModel productModel)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_Product_Create", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PRODUCTNAME", productModel.ProductName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PRODUCTDESCRIPTION", productModel.ProductDescription);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BRANDID", productModel.ProductBrandID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CATEGORYID", productModel.ProductCategoryID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PHOTOS", productModel.Photos);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PRICE", productModel.Price);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DISCOUNT", productModel.Discount);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TAX", productModel.Tax);
        con.Open();
        int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        return i;
    }
}
```

The insert of product basic information into database is working fine.

But is there a way to insert the data inside the table at the same time?

I saw this [article](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/874739/How-to-Insert-HTML-Table-Data-into-SQL-Server-in-a) but I don't know how to integrate it with my current code. Please help me.

Thank you in advance.